# Is there any danger in resetting date_default_time_zone() mid-script?

Tags: timezone

I have a cms block in /app/design/frontend/default/{mytheme}/template/cms

I was having trouble creating time-based control structures because PHP was using UTC instead of California Pacific time.

So I've inserted this at the top of the CMS phtml file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

And then I inserted this at the bottom, just in case:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Now I can use `strtotime()` and `time()` to get/set unix timestamps in the timezone of concern to me.

Is there any danger in that method? Is there a better one?

Answer (score 1):

This has a lot of implications but Magento already solved all of them. You should use the Magento helper to deal with dates and avoid using plain PHP functions in most of the cases.

By using Magento functions you will have all the setting you used in the admin like the timezone for example.

Two good guides are [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-dates-in-magento/) and [here](http://magentocookbook.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/magento-date-time/).
Another one i found from Inchoo.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any danger in that method?

if UTC is your current timezone I don't see a problem with your approach

> Is there a better one?

it is not quite clear why you only need to change the timezone for one script. Normally you would have the timezone for the server set. You can do this in php.ini with `date.timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'` or if on apache in the htaccess file with `php_value date.timezone "America/Los_Angeles"`